# AWS Cognito - Trigger Email on Password Change

Tags: email, notifications, amazon-cognito, change-password

Is there a way to trigger a notification email (to the user) in Cognito when that user's password is successfully changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this. There is a [limited set of triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) that you can link Lambdas to, but none of them fire when a user changes their password.

The closest you could get would be to use the [Custom Email Sender](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html) lambda trigger, but that only fires for passwords when a user uses the "forgot password" feature.

The only workaround I can think of is to do user auth through a custom [external SAML-based IdP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/saml-identity-provider.html), where you would have full control over password management and related triggers.